# mmap() get a 64 bit value with an offset

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I am asked this:

> Using your RPi, write a C function that reads the free running system
> timer.  The system timer counts up every microsecond.  Place the
> source for this function its own file.  The free running timer is a 64
> bit  value located at physical memory address 0x20003004, however, the
> RPi can only access 32 bits at a  time in this memory area.  To access
> these memory locations mmap() will be called on the file  /dev/mem.
> Be sure to always check for and act appropriately to errors.  To
> access the system timer:
> (a) Check to see if the counter is mapped by
> testing a static variable.
>
> (b) If the counter is not mapped then
>
> i.
> open /dev/men read only.
>
> ii. get the system page size
>
> iii. call
> mmap() and save the returned address (pointer to 32 bit integers) in a
> static variable.  call  mmap() by allowing mmap() to set the address
> mapping.  Set the length to the page size.  Set the  protection to
> read only.  Set the flags to a shared map.  Next, pass the file
> descriptor returned by  open(), and then set the offset to 0x20003000.
> Remember, for this case, mmap() can only  operate on pages of
> __SC_PAGESIZE bytes, so the address 0x20003004 cannot be directly mapped - the address must be __SC_PAGESIZE aligned.
>
> iv. Set the
> static variable to indicate that initialization has occurred.
>
> v.
> Close the open file.
>
> (c) If initialization is successful, return a 64
> bit number by combing the 32 bit value at index 1 with the  32 bit
> value at index 2.  The 32 bit value at index 1 contains the least
> significant 32 bits of the  counter.  The 32 bit value at index 2
> contains the most significant 32 bits of the counter.  Otherwise
> return 0.

I was able to get the contents of the timer for the first memory location `0x20003000` :

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int temp;
    int page_size;
    int *map;

    temp = open("/dev/mem", O_RDONLY);
    page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);


    map = mmap(0, page_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, temp, 0x20003000);
    printf("%X \n", map);

    close(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

I am lost at the part where it asks me to get the other 32 bit number `0x20003004` and combine it with the original. Any help or guidance it welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your quoted description:

> Remember, for this case, mmap() can only operate on pages of
>   __SC_PAGESIZE bytes, so the address 0x20003004 cannot be directly mapped - the address must be __SC_PAGESIZE aligned.

What this means is that `mmap()` can only map to addresses that are aligned to `__SC_PAGESIZE`. It also means that the address returned by `mmap()` can be dereferenced up to `page_size`. I.e., if the call to `mmap()` with `0x20003000` returns `0x20003000`, you can dereference pointers within `[0x20003000, 0x20003000 + page_size)`.

I'll leave the rest as an exercise for the reader.